# Is it possible to use the new graph API FQL extension with PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

Facebook announced possibility to use FQL via Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/579/

That is very nice, but I'd like to use it via PHP SDK as all my application uses it and all authorization goes through that library. I have the newest Git version of SDK, but this:

```
$facebook->api('/fql?q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()');
```

...or similar queries just don't work. It returns empty array(s) or freezes my Apache (!). What magic happens inside of the library that such an easy select or it's results can't pass through?

**EDIT:** I know I can use REST API support in PHP SDK as [you mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906850/is-it-possible-to-use-the-new-graph-api-fql-extension-with-php-sdk/7906981#7906981). I was curious about using the new method, because REST API is deprecated and very likely it won't exist any more in a couple of months. My policy is to use the latest available features Facebook released. Doing so I won't need to update my code every now and then because of using deprecated features.

**EDIT 2:** Well, I hope there is no LSD in my room... however, today I opened my browser with all my previous attempts to use different approaches mentioned above and guess what...? It works! Now I can use exactly that piece of code I wrote a few lines higher and it perfectly returns what is expected... Instead of WTF, I say: *Facebook Platform*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use `FQL` through the `api` method.

try this:

```
$fql = 'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()';
$ret_obj = $facebook->api(array(
                                 'method' => 'fql.query',
                                 'query' => $fql,
                               ));
```

As you can see you must specify that you are running an FQL query, and then pass the FQL statement into the array.

EDIT:

```
// Making a graph API call with FQL outside of the PHP SDK.

$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
. '/fql?q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()'
. '&' . $access_token;

$fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
$fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);
```

Inside the PHP SDK, you must use the `fql.query` method, there is no other way of executing an FQL query within the SDK (Yet).

Comment: I know about this possiblity. That uses REST API, which is supported in PHP SDK too from the old days. I wanted to use the new method (mentioned in linked blogpost) where FQL extends the Graph API.

Comment: @Honza the blog post goes into some detail on how to call the FQL through the graph api. I've edited my answer with the piece of relevant code from the blog for you.

Comment: see my second edit above. I am going to mark your answer as right, because the right answer would probably have to change dynamically every minute :) Yours is closest and most complete from all possible answers I think. It lists all solutions considered to be true by most of people at this moment.

Comment: haha so true, I'm pretty sure the next revision of the SDK will have an FQL query method using the graph API. However, they did mention that the REST API method won't be deprecated when all other REST API methods will be. So who knows... got to love Facebook!